# Why doesn't my 'oldUser()' run and why does it start again all the time?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, methods

I'm very very new to programming and for a school project (50% of my final grade) I had to create a Python program that did roughly this.
I've had some help from my older brother and my teacher but mainly did it myself with some flow charts etc, so please forgive me if I haven't followed conventional rules and things of this nature, or if my code is messy. I will finalise it, just needed bait of help/support from the pro's.

This is my code and I have an issue with it. Once I have pressed 'y' and then 'y' again on the displayMenu() why doesn't it run oldUser()
Also, if any of you have any suggestion on what could make my code better, or I could improve it would be very helpful and I will take it on board.

```
import os # allows me to use functions defined elsewhere. os module allows for multi platforming.
import sys
words = []
users = {}
status = ""

def teacher_enter_words():
    done = False
    print 'Hello, please can you enter a word and definition pair.'

    while not done:
            word = raw_input('\nEnter a word: ')
            deff = raw_input('Enter the definition: ')
            # append a tuple to the list so it can't be edited.
            words.append((word, deff))
            add_word = raw_input('Add another word? (y/n): ')
            if add_word.lower() == 'n':
                    done = True

def student_take_test():
    student_score = 0
    for pair in words:
            print 'Definition:', pair[1]
            inp = raw_input('Enter word: ')
            student_score += check_error(pair[0], inp)
            print 'Correct spelling:', pair[0], '\n'

    print 'Your score:', student_score

def check_error(correct, inputt):
    len_c = len(correct)
    len_i = len(inputt)
    # threshold is how many incorrect letters do we allow before a
    # minor error becomes a major error.
    # 1 - allow 1 incorrect letter for a minor error ( >= 2 becomes major error)
    threshold = 1
    # immediately check if the words are the same length
    num_letters_incorrect = abs(len_c - len_i) # abs() method returns value of x - positive dist between x and zero

    if num_letters_incorrect == 0:
            for i in xrange(0, len(correct)):
                    if correct[i] != inputt[i]:
                            num_letters_incorrect += 1

    if num_letters_incorrect <= threshold:
            if num_letters_incorrect == 0:
                    return 2 # no incorrect letter.
            else:
                    return 1 # minor error.
    else:
            return 0 # major error.

def displayMenu():
    status = raw_input('Are you a registered user? y/n?: ')
    if status == raw_input == 'y':
            oldUser()
    elif status == 'n':
            newUser()

def newUser():
    createLogin = raw_input('Create login name: ')

    if createLogin in users:
            print '\nLogin name already exist!\n'
    else:
            createPassw = raw_input('Create password: ')
            users[createLogin] = createPassw
            print '\nUser created!\n'

def oldUser():
    login = raw_input('Enter login name: ')
    passw = raw_input('Enter password: ')

    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
            print '\nLogin successful!\n'
    else:
            print "\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    running = True
    while running:
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # multi-platform, executing a shell command

            reg = raw_input('Do you want to start the program? y/n?').lower()
            if reg == 'y' or reg == 'yes':
                    displayMenu()
            else: sys.exit(0)        

            inp = raw_input('Are you a Teacher or a Student? (t/s): ').lower()
            if inp == 't' or inp == 'teacher':
                    teacher_enter_words()
            else:
                    student_take_test()
                    running = False
```

Comment: Regarding your "any suggestion on what could make my code better" question, you may have more luck on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial typo, and probably won't be useful to future readers

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` is a function. `status == raw_input == 'y'` will never be true: that is comparing status with the *function*, and with 'y'.

I suspect that's simply a typo, and you just meant `if status == 'y':`